# How to I properly setup LaTeX Workshop in VSCode with WSL2

Tags: packages, installing, paths, vscode

I am completely lost. I have installed TeXLive on windows 10 and with TeXworks I'm able to use the packages `stmaryrd`, `physics`, and `mathtools` along with the normal ams packages. However the second I try to use this in VSCode with WSL those 3 packages no longer work. I believe I have both my userpath and system path setup right but just in case in my path variable in both places I have the following line `C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32`. I'm very lost as to why these packages are not found in VSCode but are found in TeXworks. I have looked through the github wiki for this extension but to no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you have those packages in your Windows distribution but not under WSL? I only use the WSL2 (Ubuntu) engine to compile TeX code on my Windows box, but I don't have any LaTeX compiler in my Windows folders.

If you don't have TeX Live in your WSL distribution, you can install it by running

```
sudo apt install texlive
```

I realize this question is 2 years old, but it might help someone like me who found it while looking for something else.

Comment: I appreciate the response, however late it is.